# App Crash : Android using Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am writing an application using android studio and using fragments.
The application crashes when I am trying to load the fragment dynamically.

I am adding the codes below.

fragment_setup.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pchakraverti.streetsecure.setup_fragment"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/prgLayout">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layoutMode="opticalBounds"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60sp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="20px"
            android:layout_height="20px" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Later"
            android:id="@+id/btnLater" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:hint="Address"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:hint="Phone No." />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:hint="Email" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Fill in the form below."
        android:id="@+id/lblHeader"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

setup_fragment.java

```
package com.example.pchakraverti.streetsecure;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link setup_fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link setup_fragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class setup_fragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment setup_fragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static setup_fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        setup_fragment fragment = new setup_fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public setup_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setup_fragment, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

activity_start.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    tools:context=".StartActivity">

</LinearLayout>
```

StartActivity.java

```
package com.example.pchakraverti.streetsecure;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class StartActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        setup_fragment frag = new setup_fragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_container, frag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The setup_fragment contains the UI which I want to load when the application starts.
However, The application crashes on startup.

I've used this tutorial for loading the fragment :
[Dynamically add Fragments to an Activity in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-fragments-to-an-activity-in-android/)

Some help will be appreciated.

*EDIT*

As for logcat, I donot see anything on logcat(I dont know why).
[image: Here is the Screenshot]

Comment: Your Activity `" must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener"`. Also, if you're using FragmentActivity, all of your Fragment-related classes need to come from the support library.

Comment: it write in the comments above setup_ftagment.
 Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link setup_fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You instantiate your Fragment like this :

```
new setup_fragment()
```

Instead, use the factory method you defined :

```
setup_fragment frag = setup_fragment.newInstance(string1, string2);
```

Your `Fragment` also requires the `Activity` to implement the `OnFragmentInteractionListener` interface, so you need to implement the `onFragmentInteraction` method in your `Activity`, and declare your `Activity` as follows :

```
StartActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

If, as I suspect, you just used the code generated by your IDE but are not planning to use all of it, you could also simply remove the parts you don't need, factory methods and the interface for the Activity are only provided for your convenience but not formally required.

Finally, as pointed out by Neige, you're mixing up `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Fix your imports. If you want to app to use the support library to support older OS versions, make sure the correct classes are imported (`FragmentManager`, `FragmentTransaction`, ... have a corresponding class in the support library).

On a side note, many developpers will probably appreciate it if you use the most used naming convention in Java, namely [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using support library (v4 for fragment), you need to extends setup_fragment to  android.support.v4.app.fragment instead of android.app.Fragment;